# Can't find my error in accepts_nested_attributes_for syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-attributes

In my Receipt model:

```
  attr_accessible ..., :donor_contacts_attributes
  has_many :donor_contacts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :donor_contacts
```

In my DonorContact model:

```
  belongs_to :receipt
```

In my controller new action:

```
@receipt = Receipt.new
@donor_contact = DonorContact.new
```

The error that I get on save:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: donor_contact
```

I don't see what I've done wrong. Any of you see it? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In your Receipt model try to change

```
attr_accessible ..., :donor_contacts_attributes
```

by

```
attr_accessible ..., :donor_contact_attributes
```

Comment: Did you try, in the new action of your control to do "@receipt = Receipt.new @donor_contact = DonorContact.build" , then in the create action  "@donor_contact = @receipt.build_donor_contact(params[:donor_contact])"